# Eliminate space in word file

Tags: vba, ms-word

in my word file there are hundrens of paragraph which like the format below. There is a single letter Y here. It can be other letter except "A","T","C","G". I want to remove the white space in it then create a new line.

```
AAATGGGCCC CACAGAAGTG AGAATGGGTG AAGTCAGAAT TCCTGGTAAT GAAGTGCTTG
AACTTGGATT CCTCCCGACA TGTGCAGTAC AATGAGATGA TTTTCTCCTT AATGAGATTA
GGAAATTCTA TTAGCGCTCC CAGCTGCTGA CCCGATTCCA TGAGGCTGAG GCTCCAGGGC
TGAACCTGCC TGGTT
Y
AGTGTTCCTG GAAACTAGAC ACCCCACCCT TCAGATGGGC CAGGGCCTCC CCAGCTCTAC
CTAAAGCTGT GGTCTGCCCC CAGGGGTGCC CAGTTTCCTC CCTTCACCCT GTGCTCCAGA
GGAGTGTGGG GCCCTGGGCA TTCTGCAGTG TACCCCAGGA TCCTCACTCC TTCCTGCTTA
```

The new line's format is

```
AAATGGGCCCCACAGAAGTGAGAATGGGTGAAGTCAGAATTCCTGGTAATGAAGTGCTTGAACTTGGATTCCTCCCGACATGTGCAGTACAATGAGATGATTTTCTCCTTAATGAGATTAGGAAATTCTATTAGCGCTCCCAGCTGCTGACCCGATTCCATGAGGCTGAGGCTCCAGGGCTGAACCTGCCTGGTT[Y]AGTGTTCCTGGAAACTAGACACCCCACCCTTCAGATGGGCCAGGGCCTCCCCAGCTCTACCTAAAGCTGTGGTCTGCCCCCAGGGGTGCCCAGTTTCCTCCCTTCACCCTGTGCTCCAGAGGAGTGTGGGGCCCTGGGCATTCTGCAGTGTACCCCAGGATCCTCACTCCTTCCTGCTTA
```

Notice Y becomes [Y].

The final result will be saved as a text file. Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you want to do this once or do you want a VB script in word to do this? (I noticed the Word-vba tag).

Comment: You mean like a macro or a VB program ? And at least have you tried to something ?

Comment: Actually I want to run a macro such as clicking a button in a blank word file then blah blah. The result can be found in a text file.

Comment: Mapping the genome in VBA? What is the world coming to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write a program. The “Replace” tool is sufficient for this:

1. Replace `Y` with `[Y]` (EDIT: see the comments below, because it's a little more complex than that indeed)
2. Replace `^w` with nothing (`^w` means *whitespace*)
3. Replace `^p` with nothing (`^p` means *paragraph markers*)

EDIT: if you need a macro, just do the above once while recording a macro.

EDIT: by applying the method discussed in the comments, I get the following VBA macro:

```
Sub ProcessATCG()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "([!ACGT^13^32])"
        .Replacement.Text = "[\1]"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[^13^32]"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: The question the seperate letter may not always be "Y". There are thousands of paragraphs.

Comment: The size of the document does not matter as long as you hit “Replace all” ;-)   Is the set of “separate letters” well-defined? What are these?

Comment: They can be "Y","Z","X" etc. Any letter except"A","G","C","T".

Comment: Okay. Then you may do the first step as follows. In the dialog click “more” and then check “use wildcards”. Use as search string: `([!ACGT^13^32])` (any character other than A, C, G, T or newline or space). Use as replace string: `[\1]` (the expression matched in the parentheses above, between brackets).

Comment: Thanks. But if I insist on vba, what is the code like? Because the guy who wants to replace the whitespaces doesn't know these function at all. He feels the steps are too complexed. He just wants a robot machine, clicking a button...then..

Comment: @ardmore: I have edited my answer above and added VBA code from the macro recorder. Works like a charm for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. You removed all ^p.How can I distinguish the pragraphs? Each pragraph will generate one line. The lines are still seperated by ^p.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I did not mention that. I factored the elimination of spaces and newlines in the second replace operation. `[^13^32]` means *newline or space*.